# Writing Code within a Range

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I am writing an excel program for tracking where tools at our workplace are located. I am trying to move data from one page to another. I have VLookup to access the information but I want to be able to clear the contents of the other page once the details are found. The  problem I have is writng a formula in the VBA code(since this is a button that activates it all) that can Find the row and then clear the contents of that row. I have tried putting a match formula in a random cell to find the row and was trying to input that into the range automatically. Does anyone know how this is possible?
This is what I've been trying. X1 has a match formula in that Cell.

Sheets("Running.Sheet").Range("A"Running.Sheet").Range("X1").Value).ClearContents

Answer (score 1):

Almost there. Try

```
Sheets("Running.Sheet").Range("A" & Sheets("Running.Sheet").Range("X1").Value).ClearContents
```

You can make the code a bit more manageable by declaring variables for the sheet, assigning the sheet name to the variable and then using the variable. Like this:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Running.Sheet")

ws.Range("A" & ws.Range("X1").Value).ClearContents
```

Although it's a bit more work to set up, you gain efficiencies the more often you need to refer to that same sheet.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: nice one,,, `ws.Range("A" & ws.Range("X1").Value)`  ,, since `Range A` is part of  the same Sheet.   +10 ☺